# Accessing Docker Volume content on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-volume

When I do a `docker volume inspect <dockerid>` on a Mac, I can see the path to the data, this appears as a `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume name>`

On a Mac, this link does not exist, because docker runs on inside a very tiny VM.

I can use `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` to get into the vm and then navigate to the folder to see the volumes.

So got all that, but my question is: **How do I link what is in these volumes on my host machine?**

I have tried this: `docker run -it --volume hello:/hello2 --name access_volumes busybox:latest /bin/sh` Where hello is the name of a volume I have created.

I can link a folder on my host machine to the container, but I want to backup the content or edit the content of the Volume from my host machine.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without a container.
You need something along the lines of [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) for backup:

```
docker run --rm --volume hello:/data -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

or for modifying:

```
docker run -d --name access_volume --volume hello:/data busybox
docker cp access_volume:/data local-data
# modify local-data
docker cp local-data access_volume:/data
```

Comment: This worked for me in the end with all my other building blocks I had. Thanks for the solution

Comment: If you created the volume with Docker-Compose, prefix it with the foldername. You can check the volumes with 'docker volume ls'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you known docker-compose: you can link your folder to the container by `volumes`
you can link like this

```
volumes:
  - ./your_host_folder:/folder_in_container/
```

Comment: Yes I have used compose - is that the only way I can access the volume though? Or can I access the Volume directly without a container present?

Comment: Yeah that access the folder on my host machine, but it doesn't access the volume. I want to have a format like this: host-folder => docker-volume => docker-container

Comment: Cool and if I can access the volume without having load a container that would be better. I want the volume to be decoupled from the container. Since docker creates the volume and leaves it on my machine unless I specifically delete it, I must be able to access it right?

Answer (score 1):

for example, you create a Volume with a File Docker-Compose.yml:

...

```
influxdb:
 image: influxdb:latest
 container_name: influxdb
 restart: always
 ports:
   - "8086:8086"
   - "9092:9092"
 volumes:
  - type: volume
    source: vol_influxdb
    target: /var/lib/influxdb
```

...

You can't find this Volume "vol_influxdb" on your Mac, because it's in the Docker-VM. Start your Mac-Terminal an Enter:

```
screen /Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty
```

Now you are in the Docker-VM and you can search your Volume with:

```
cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/<VolumeName>/_data/
```

Comment: When I type screen tty I get : [screen is terminating]
My containers are running and I'm in the right directory. I tried also as root.
Any tip? Thanks

Comment: @Giggioz: the code 
`screen /Users/$USER/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` doesn't work, check this:

**[docker/for-mac](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822)**
__and__
**[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445657/why-i-am-getting-screen-is-terminating-error-in-macos/63595817#63595817)**